# Problematic NVIDIA driver installation in linux

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 22.04

I have updated recently my drivers in Ubuntu 22.04LTS for the NVIDIA GeForce MX150 to the version 535.86.10 and installed cuda 12.2. I got the newest drivers by `sudo ubuntu-driver install` and the cuda 12.2 from nvidia directly. However, I get the following output when I am running `nvidia-smi`:

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 535.86.10              Driver Version: 535.86.10    CUDA Version: 12.2     |
|-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                 Persistence-M | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp   Perf          Pwr:Usage/Cap |         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                      |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce MX150           On  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   48C    P8              N/A / ERR! |      4MiB /  2048MiB |      0%      Default |
|                                         |                      |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                                         
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                            |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                            GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                             Usage      |
|=======================================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      2305      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                            4MiB |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Why do I get so many N/A and why is there even an "ERR!" in the middle? I cannot really understand this table, since I didn't find much information in its [documentation](https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/DCGM/docs/nvidia-smi-367.38.pdf)

Comment: It is unclear how many driver are there. You've only mentioned one version. Did you get many drivers of that version? How many? The document you've mentioned explains what N/A means in several places. Do look it up. There seems to be nothing problematic about this driver install or update or get ...whatever you call it.

Comment: The 22.04 Nvidia driver from the restricted repos is 535.86.05, not 535.86.10.  The Ubuntu repo drivers come with update scripts so a kernel or driver update will rebuild the driver.  Also of note, right now, doing an upgrade did get the 535.86.05, but policy show an 80% phased on the nvidia-driver-535, so that may cause some problems.

Comment: @mikewhatever you are right, I looked up for "ERR!" in the documentation, not for "N/A", but still the documentation is apparently not up to date and I could not find there anything. I did tho in a random Medium article and at least I understand more of the output now.

Comment: @ubfan1 `sudo ubuntu-drivers install` gave me that version directly, I did not select anything. In "Additional Drivers" I can see only "nvidia-driver-525" as a tested driver. But if this driver does not have actually any problem, then I'm happy to leave it as it is.

Comment: If you use the graphics-drivers PPA, it may have the 86.10 and will be OK, but the CUDA 12.2 does offer the 86.10, and if used, will probably cause problems when a normal kernel update occurs and the driver needs to be rebuilt.